# Django - Static files serving javascript , css and image files

Tags: django, django-templates

I need to server static files in my Django project.

I would like to place them in /static directory and be able to reference them in my templates.

I've been reading "Managing static files" in the documentation and I am confused.  I've followed the instructions but am not able to get it to work.

1) I have put my static files in /static under each app in my project.

2)  django.contrib.staticfiles is included under my INSTALLED_APPS.

I've set the following variables in settings:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/static/'
STATIC_URL  = '/static/'
```

In my template I have the following line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src={{ STATIC_URL }}/a_ajax.js></script>
```

however when I bring up the page and look at source the line is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=/a_ajax.js></script>
```

It seems like nothing was passed to the template.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9):

Considering that you are using Django 1.4 or higher, here is my explanation:

In Django 1.3 the static files were separated from the uploaded files (media) and now,  they have their own home.

To serve static files (css, js, images, etc) in the development environment you need:

1. Put these files in their respective app's `static` subdirectory
2. Make sure you have `django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder` in your `settings.py` (this is the default behavior)

The directory structure will be:

```
__| project_root/
____| your_app/
______| static/
________| test.css
________| some.js
```

So the request to `http://localhost:8000/static/test.css` will be routed to `your_app/static/test.css`.

Note that you don't need to change `STATIC_ROOT` setting, until you go to production environment that you will need to run `./manage.py collectstatic`.

The `collectstatic` command will collect files from the app's `static` subdirectories and put them all in an unique place (the directory defined in `STATIC_ROOT`)

If you are going to deploy your project in production, see [./manage.py collectstatic documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-collectstatic).

Comment: FYI: More recent Django versions recommend another `your_app` subdirectory (i.e. `project_root/your_app/static/your_app/`) to put the files in to protect against name collisions: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/ (note the version selector in the lower right!)

Answer (score 2):

Include `'django.core.context_processors.static'` is in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` var in `settings.py`.

see documentation: [Referring to static files in templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#referring-to-static-files-in-templates)

### Update:

And in the view, use the `RequestContext` object instead of the `Context` object.

```
def view1(request):
    ...
    context = RequestContext(...
    return render_to_response( ... , context )
```

Comment: I included that -  no change - there must be another problem also.

Comment: It must be the `RequestContext` I forgot to mention. See my edit.

Comment: I have learned google app engine has a different method by updating app.yaml file which is much simpler than the native method offered by Django.  I have used extensions /js/jquery.js - GAE maps /js/  to specific directory for static files.

Comment: Check http://agiliq.com/blog/2013/03/serving-static-files-in-django/. This might help clear things a bit.

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of Django, this is how I link to static files in a html template:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/labeler.js' %}"> </script>`

Django docs on STATIC are here: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/